# Python 3 rock, paper, scissors issue

Tags: python

I am working on a rock, paper, scissors game for a programming homework assignment and I have run into a little snag. The program is suppose run by the user selecting 1 of 4 options, 1) rock, 2) paper, 3) scissors and 4) quit. Once the player selects an option the computers selection is displayed and the winner is announced and the program will ask if you would like to play another game. If y is select you go back to the main menu to choose another option, anything else will bring up the amount of games won, lost and how many games ended in a tie. If the player selects 4 the program should say "Exiting program..." and the game results should display.

Here are my issues:

1. Once you make the first selection, the winner is displayed and the program returns to main menu. If you make a second selection it will inform you of what the computer chose and then ask if you would like to play again. Y will take you back to the main menu, the computers selection will never change and no matter what you select the game will always end in the same result as the very first game. If you choose not to play again then the amount of games won, lost and tied will appear (this seems to be functioning correctly).
2. The quit option takes you back to the main menu instead of displaying the game results. I am not sure where to put that if statement.

Any help with these issues would be appreciated.

Thank you

```
#import module
import random

def main():
    #create a variable to control the loop
    play_again = 'y'

    #create a counter for tied games, computer games and player games
    tied_games = 0
    computer_games = 0
    player_games = 0

    #display opening message
    print("Let's play rock, paper scissors!") 

    computer_choice = process_computer_choice()

    player_choice = process_player_choice()

    winner = determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice)

    #setup while loop for playing multiple games
    while play_again == 'y' or play_again == 'Y':

        process_computer_choice()

        process_player_choice()

        #use a if else statement to print the computers choice
        if computer_choice == 1:
            print('computer chooses rock.')

        elif computer_choice == 2:
            print('computer chooses paper.')

        else:
            print('computer chooses scissors.')

            #call the determine winner function    
            determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice)

        #check who won the game and add 1 to the correct counter
        if winner == 'computer':
            computer_games += 1

        elif winner == 'player':
            player_games += 1

        else:
            tied_games += 1

        #ask the user if they would like to play again    
        play_again = input('would you like to play again? (enter y for yes): ')

    #display number of games that were won by the computer, the player and that were tied
    print()
    print('there was', tied_games, 'tied games.')
    print('the player won', player_games, 'games.')
    print('The computer won', computer_games,'games.')

#define the process computer function
def process_computer_choice():

    #setup computer to select random integer between 1 and 3
    choice1 = random.randint(1, 3)

    #return the computers choice
    return choice1

#define the process player function
def process_player_choice():

    #add input for players choice
    print()
    print('        MENU')
    print('1) Rock!')
    print('2) Paper!')
    print('3) Scissors!')
    print('4) Quit')
    print()

    player_choice = int(input('Please make a selection:  '))

    #add if statement for quit option
    if player_choice == 4:
        print('Exiting program....')

   #validate if the user enters a correct selection
    while player_choice != 1 and player_choice != 2 and player_choice != 3 and player_choice != 4:

        #print a error message if the wrong selection is entered
        print('Error! Please enter a correct selection.')

        player_choice = int(input('Please make a selection: '))

    #return the players choice
    return player_choice

#define the determine winner function
def determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice):

    #setup if else statements for each of the 3 computer selections
    if computer_choice == 1:
        if player_choice == 2:
            print('Paper wraps rock. You win!')
            winner = 'player'

        elif player_choice == 3:
            print('Rock smashes scissors. The computer wins!')
            winner = 'computer'

        else:
            print('The game is tied. Try again.')
            winner = 'tied'

    if computer_choice == 2:
        if player_choice == 1:
            print('Paper wraps rock. The computer wins!')
            winner = 'computer'

        elif player_choice == 3:
            print('Scissors cut paper. You win!')
            winner = 'player'

        else:
            print('The game is tied. Try again.')
            winner = 'tied'

    if computer_choice == 3:
        if player_choice == 1:
            print('Rock smashes scissors. You win!')
            winner = 'player'

        elif player_choice == 2:
            print('Scissors cut paper. The computer wins!')
            winner = 'computer'

        else:
            print('The game is tied. Try again.')
            winner = 'tied'

    return winner

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For issue 1, it's because you set the computer and player choices before your loop, and never update them. Change the beginning of your loop to:

```
while play_again == 'y' or play_again == 'Y':
    computer_choice = process_computer_choice()
    player_choice = process_player_choice()
```

You can also remove the lines of code before the loop that check the inputs and winner, as it's technically redundant for the first round.

For issue 2, just add the results after a 4 is chosen, like so:

```
if player_choice == 4:
      print('Exiting program....')  
      print('there was', tied_games, 'tied games.')
      print('the player won', player_games, 'games.')
      print('The computer won', computer_games,'games.')
      sys.exit() # be sure you add 'import sys' to the beginning of your file
```

Also, the line in your main loop `determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice)` is indented so it will only be called if the computer chooses scissors, so you should unindent that :)

Comment: just use return  instead of sys.exit

Comment: He checks if player choice is 4 in a function that's called by main though, so wouldn't this require exit? Obviously the best way is to check in main(), but with his structure wouldn't this be right?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't assigning to `computer_choice` or `player_choice` again, but using it's value.

```
while play_again == 'y' or play_again == 'Y':

    process_computer_choice()

    process_player_choice()
```

Should be

```
while play_again == 'y' or play_again == 'Y':

    computer_choice = process_computer_choice()

    player_choice = process_player_choice()
```

As for quitting just break in the quit choice. You have to return early from the process_player_choice and also do something in main.

So in process_player_choice:

```
if player_choice == 4:
    print('Exiting program....')
    return
```

and in main:
    player_choice = process_player_choice()

```
if player_choice == 4:
     return 

winner = determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice)

#setup while loop for playing multiple games
while play_again == 'y' or play_again == 'Y':

    computer_choice = process_computer_choice()

    player_choice = process_player_choice()
    if player_choice == 4:
         break
```

Comment: `if player_choice == 4:` is not in a loop so you cannot use break, you would use return

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, ` while play_again == 'y' or play_again == 'Y':` is not a loop?

Comment: My solution would mean that quit on the first round would do nothing, but thereafter would work properly. It's probably not the ideal.

Comment: the if statement is outside the while loop in the OP's code, return will work

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, you are right for the first choice, return will work, but for the choice in the loop break is correct as it will print the result after and then quit. I also missed adding a return from the input function.