# Adding input validation to my Rock Paper Scissor PYTHON

Tags: python, validation, input

I am trying to add input validation to this so the user can only enter ROCK, rock, PAPER, paper, SCISSORS or scissors. I am unsure about where to add it, and really how to do it as an if statement.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Of course I would need to finish the game after they corrected their answer

```
import random


def main():
    x = random.randint(1, 3)
    rock = "ROCK, rock"
    paper = "PAPER, paper"
    scissors = "SCISSORS, scissors"
    if x == 1:
        x = 'ROCK'
    elif x == 2:
        x = 'PAPER'
    elif x == 3:
        x = 'SCISSORS'
    guess = raw_input('rock, paper or scissors?: ')
    print('CPU: ', x, 'Player: ', guess)
    result = winner(x, guess)
    if result == 'tie':
        print('Its a tie try again!')
        main()
    else:
        print(result, 'Wins')

def winner(x, guess):
    if guess == 'scissors' and x == 'ROCK':
        win = 'rock'
        return win
    elif guess == 'paper' and x == 'SCISSORS':
        win = 'scissors'
        return win
    elif guess == 'paper' and x == 'ROCK':
        win = 'paper'
        return win
    elif guess == 'rock' and x == 'PAPER':
        win = 'paper'
        return win
    elif guess == 'rock' and x == 'SCISSORS':
        win = 'rock'
        return win
    else:
        win = 'tie'
        return win
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456215/python-3-rock-paper-scissors-issue/26456305 of any help

Comment: You might want to look into the `lower()` method of python strings. This will simplify your code, e.g. `'rOcK'.lower() == 'rock'`

Answer (score 2):

right after `guess = raw_input('rock, paper or scissors?: ')` , you could check with a simple:

```
if guess not in ('ROCK', 'rock', 'PAPER', 'paper', 'SCISSORS', 'scissors') : ...
```

Note 1:
Instead of handling 'ROCK' and 'rock' , etc. I suggest you convert user input to uppercase, and only handle upper case strings :

```
guess = raw_input('rock, paper or scissors?: ')
guess = guess.upper()
```

Note 2:
I suggest you have a list of all possible answers :

```
valid_choices = ('ROCK','PAPER','SCISSORS')
```

and then just do:

```
guess = raw_input('rock, paper or scissors?: ')
guess = guess.upper()
if guess not in valid_choices : ... #handle error here.
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps. Once I run it though, i get this in the editor

`rock, paper or scissors?:  cat

Please enter rock, paper or scissors:
('CPU: ', 'ROCK', 'Player: ', 'cat')
Its a tie try again!
rock, paper or scissors?:`
Then it says its a tie, to try again. how can i write it so it doesnt? Ill add my code as next answer

Answer (score 0):

If I run this and type CATS, it will say "Enter rock paper or scissors" like its supposed to, but it also says its a tie, which is.. wrong. So, after a wrong input, it should basically go back to user input

```
import random


def main():
    x = random.randint(1, 3)
    rock = "ROCK, rock"
    paper = "PAPER, paper"
    scissors = "SCISSORS, scissors"
    if x == 1:
        x = 'ROCK'
    elif x == 2:
        x = 'PAPER'
    elif x == 3:
        x = 'SCISSORS'
    guess = raw_input('rock, paper or scissors?: ')
    if guess not in ('ROCK', 'rock', 'PAPER', 'paper', 'SCISSORS', 'scissors'):
        print"Please enter rock, paper or scissors:"


    result = winner(x, guess)
    print('CPU: ', x, 'Player: ', guess)
    if result == 'tie':
        print('Its a tie try again!')
        main()
    else:
        print(result, 'Wins')

def winner(x, guess):
    if guess == 'scissors' and x == 'ROCK':
        win = 'rock'
        return win
    elif guess == 'paper' and x == 'SCISSORS':
        win = 'scissors'
        return win
    elif guess == 'paper' and x == 'ROCK':
        win = 'paper'
        return win
    elif guess == 'rock' and x == 'PAPER':
        win = 'paper'
        return win
    elif guess == 'rock' and x == 'SCISSORS':
        win = 'rock'
        return win
    else:
        win = 'tie'
        return win
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: that's because if it's not a valid choice, then you need to ask the question again instead of moving on to processing. You need to have a loop, see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

that's because if it's not a valid choice, then you need to ask the question again instead of moving on to processing. You need to have a loop, for instance:

```
valid_choices = ('ROCK','PAPER','SCISSORS')

while True:
    guess = raw_input('rock, paper or scissors?: ')
    guess = guess.upper()
    if guess in valid_choices : break

result = winner(x, guess)
print('CPU: ', x, 'Player: ', guess)
```